# How to fill small gaps in unregular, infrequent time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series with data arriving plus/minus every five minutes. Sometimes there is no data at all for certain timestamps resulting in big gaps.

What's the best approach to fill (ff/bf) small gaps smaller than a certain threshold (say < 30 min) of lacking data?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['2016-01-01 00:04:41', 1.0, 0.0005],
    ['2016-01-01 00:09:44', 2.5, 0.0004],
    ['2016-01-01 00:14:46', 3.1, 0.0003],
    ['2016-01-01 00:19:48', 2.1, 0.0002],
    ['2016-01-01 00:49:43', 2.1, 0.0002],
    ['2016-01-01 03:19:33', 2.1, 0.0005],
    ['2016-01-01 04:19:01', 2.1, 0.0009],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['timestamp','A', 'B'])

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
#df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df = df.set_index('timestamp').resample('5T').asfreq()

df
```

Comment: Depends on the data. Have you tried https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html? Smaller gaps can be filled with `NaN`s, whereas larger ones can be left out, making pandas fill in only the smaller ones. I would start by calculating time delta for each record.

Comment: What do you mean by "drop a gap"?

Comment: @chepner you're right, doesn't make any sense